# Protobuf error: Bad type on operand stack

Tags: java, hive, protobuf-java

My team has been trying to deploy a setup in our hive production system, where a hql file calls a jar passing some input, and the jar gives some output. The java code runs absolutely fine on terminal, but on hive, throws the following error at times.

```
Vertex failed, vertexName=Map 1, vertexId=vertex_1672281536650_0001_1_00, diagnostics=[Task failed, taskId=task_1672281536650_0001_1_00_000003, diagnostics=[TaskAttempt 0 failed, info=[Error: Error while running task ( failure ) : attempt_1672281536650_0001_1_00_000003_0:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack
Exception Details:
  Location:
    com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessageV3$ExtendableMessage.getExtension(Lcom/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage$GeneratedExtension;)Ljava/lang/Object; @2: invokevirtual
  Reason:
    Type 'com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage$GeneratedExtension' (current frame, stack[1]) is not assignable to 'com/google/protobuf/ExtensionLite'
  Current Frame:
    bci: @2
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessageV3$ExtendableMessage', 'com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage$GeneratedExtension' }
    stack: { 'com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessageV3$ExtendableMessage', 'com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage$GeneratedExtension' }
  Bytecode:
    0x0000000: 2a2b b600 23b0                         

    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:211)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.run(TezProcessor.java:168)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.run(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:374)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable$1.run(TaskRunner2Callable.java:73)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable$1.run(TaskRunner2Callable.java:61)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1844)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable.callInternal(TaskRunner2Callable.java:61)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable.callInternal(TaskRunner2Callable.java:37)
    at org.apache.tez.common.CallableWithNdc.call(CallableWithNdc.java:36)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack
Exception Details:
  Location:
    com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessageV3$ExtendableMessage.getExtension(Lcom/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage$GeneratedExtension;)Ljava/lang/Object; @2: invokevirtual
  Reason:
    Type 'com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage$GeneratedExtension' (current frame, stack[1]) is not assignable to 'com/google/protobuf/ExtensionLite'
  Current Frame:
    bci: @2
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessageV3$ExtendableMessage', 'com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage$GeneratedExtension' }
    stack: { 'com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessageV3$ExtendableMessage', 'com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage$GeneratedExtension' }
  Bytecode:
    0x0000000: 2a2b b600 23b0
```

The first line of the stack trace error:
`at edu.stanford.nlp.simple.Document.<init>(Document.java:400)` 
In the jar we are using stanford core nlp as a dependency, protobuf becomes a transient dependency. The code runs fine at times and throws the above error other times, which is making it even more confusing for us.

Any help in resolving this error would be highly appreciated.

My initial guess was that maybe some version incompatibility was causing this behavior. I have tried using the latest stanford core nlp v4.5.1 jar from maven, and pairing that with the latest protobuf v3.21.12 on one instance and also with protobuf v3.19.2 (which was defined in the pom file file of core nlp) on a different instance. But I got the same result both the times.

Comment: Hey Santanu, any luck in getting this resolved, I'm facing the same issue and wracking my head around it :(.

Comment: that's me - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75212937/dependency-conflict-management-in-pom-for-apache-beam-pipeline-caused-by-java